# Rectangle is not displaying on stage?

Tags: java, javafx

I have written a program where a lightblue rectangle gets added in a pane. The pane is then added in the scene. The stage is then shown with the rectangle in the scene. When I run this program, the opposite happens. Nothing shows up. Even when I add, let's say text, nothing shows up either. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong? I am using JavaFX as the GUI. Here's my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class RectangleBound extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane p = new Pane();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setFill(Color.LIGHTSKYBLUE);
        rect.setStroke(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);
        rect.setArcWidth(5);
        // *C* set the width of the outline of rect to 5

        p.getChildren().add(rect);

        Scene sc = new Scene(p, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Bound Rectangle");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a width and height to the Rectangle. Just try the following and it should work.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);
```